# 60s comic character who resembled Gru

Tags: comics, character-identification, despicable-me

In a UK comic back in the sixties, there was some villain who looked like Gru (from *Despicable Me*), but he did a big grin sometimes, and then bats flew out his mouth.

Comment: Which comics did you read in the 1960s? Was he in colour or black'n'white? Was the villain the main character or an antagonist? Were these *literal* bats flying out of his mouth? In what way did he look like Gru?

Comment: I read loads of different comics in the sixties. Pretty much all the standard comics for uk schoolboys so that doesn't help much. He was a amusingly evil main character like Gru. Bald like Gru . wanted to rule the world with evil but insane plots. Yes bats flew out. I think it was the typical "full colour" of the day, which was usually black and white with occasional bit of red! Also I've just remembered he had like little creatures to help as well

Comment: Could it be : http://hanna-barbera.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Gruesome from Wacky Races ? The bats made me think of this . . .

Comment: @Pat Dobson. No sorry, I've looked at the Gruesomes and it's not. The one I'm trying to remember was bald like Gru and uncle fester -- maybe a scarf or tie like Gru as well (maybe!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**Grimly Feendish**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimly_Feendish)

[image: character with bat exiting his mouth]

[image: Grimly welcoming a new guest]

> Grimly Feendish was a supervillain who sought to conquer the world,
> using both his monsters and bizarre plot devices, such as exploding
> treacle, to do so. He was usually thwarted by Eagle-Eye, Junior Spy.
> At one point Grimly started Doomsday School for young monsters across
> the road from Eagle-Eye's school, Conker Crescent High. One of the
> students at Doomsday School was Grimly's nephew, Fred Feendish, who
> became friends with Eagle-Eye and would sometimes try to warn him of
> his uncle's schemes.
>
> [Source](http://www.internationalhero.co.uk/g/grimfien.htm)

A Google search for "Gru british comic 1960's" turned up the info fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you. I had a google before I asked in here but failed to find this. Definitely Grimly Feendish!

Comment: excellent! Glad to help @Danny3414